# Как добавить дефис в атрибуте pattern в html

Tags: html

Есть следующая строка:

```
 <input id="nick" name="nick" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_]{5,15}" required>
```

Я хочу разрешить использование только латинских символов, цифр, нижних подчеркиваний и дефиса. Но если пишу вот так:

```
<input id="nick" name="nick" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9-_]{5,15}" required>
```

То у меня паттерн вообще перестает работать и принимает все символы. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте перед `-` поставить ```\```, т.е. `\-`

Comment: Результат изменился, но теперь я просто не могу использовать тире

Comment: А, все, исправилось) Теперь все работает отлично, спасибо!

Comment: @XlAlbertlX: Всё немного проще - просто указывайте дефис последним - `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`